# Pulumi "error deleting Autoscaling Launch Configuration" with aws.eks.NodeGroup

Tags: pulumi

I am getting the following error while running `pulumi up`, I am getting a `templateBody` update in the preview for `aws:cloudformation:Stack spot-ng-01-nodes`.

```
 aws:ec2:LaunchConfiguration (spot-ng-01-nodeLaunchConfiguration):
 error: deleting urn:pulumi:staging::xx-api::eks:index:NodeGroup$aws:ec2/launchConfiguration:LaunchConfiguration::spot-ng-01-nodeLaunchConfiguration: 1 error occurred:
 * error deleting Autoscaling Launch Configuration (spot-ng-01-nodeLaunchConfiguration-3a59b7e): ResourceInUse: Cannot delete launch configuration spot-ng-01-nodeLaunchConfiguration-3a59b7e because it is attached to AutoScalingGroup spot-ng-01-d1815eb6-NodeGroup-UBM7XABBGVNU
 status code: 400, request id: fc55d507-0884-4c50-aeba-33831646a914
```

This is the resource in question, but the code was not updated.

```
new eks.NodeGroup("spot-ng-01", {
              cluster: cluster,
              spotPrice: "0.1",
              instanceType: "t3.xlarge",
              taints,
              labels: { spot: "true" },
              version: "1.21",
              maxSize: 60,
              minSize: 1,
              nodeSubnetIds: options.vpc.privateSubnetIds,
              instanceProfile: new aws.iam.InstanceProfile("spot-ng-profile-01", { role: role.name }),
              nodeAssociatePublicIpAddress: false,
              nodeSecurityGroup: clusterSG,
              clusterIngressRule: cluster.eksClusterIngressRule,
              autoScalingGroupTags: {
                  Name: "spot",
                  "k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/enabled": "true",
                  [`k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/${clusterName}`]: "true",
              },
          });
```

Even after running `pulumi refresh`, I still get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution required manual intervention, it might not be the best but it solved the issue.

Another LaunchConfiguration was created by pulumi, I made this new LaunchConfiguration used by the AutoscalingGroup in question. then I ran `pulumi up` and it was able to delete the LaunchConfiguration that was stuck. Then ran `pulumi refresh`.